# How to use Tensorflow with an already existing Keras LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to perform a reinforcement learning experiment on top of an LSTM model.

The LSTM model performs an entity recognition on four entities (Products, Person, Location and others).

Now I want to use Tensorforce as an reinforcement learning engine along with my LSTM model for reinforcing misclassified events back into the model for a better model accuracy and performance.How can I achieve it ?

I came across Proximal Policy Optimisation? Is this what I should be using?